# Trigger Event based on Form Input Length

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-events

I am trying to autosave the form whenever the form length changes.
Below is my code. Initial form length is recorded correctly and variable `$("form input").length` do change when I play with the form but the block inside the if statement is not triggered.

Anyone knows why this is?

```
var formLength = $("form input").length;
console.log("the current formLength is" + formLength);

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("form input").length > formLength) {
    setTimeout(autoSaveForm, 10000);

    formLength = $("form input").length;

    console.log("the updated formLength is" + formLength);
  }
});
```

Update: Florian has perfectly solved this problem. And I have an update of one new problem. The form I have is a nested form using Cocoon gem in rails. A datepicker.js is loaded whenever one child inside the nest is added.

However the datepicker is only loaded after the set time interval.

Below is my new code. Any thoughts?

var formLength = $("form input").length;
    console.log("the current formLength is : " + formLength);

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each($('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]'), function(index, element) {
    if (element.value) {
      var dsplit = element.value.split("-");
      var d =new Date(dsplit[0],dsplit[1]-1,dsplit[2]);
      element.value = d;
    }
    new Pikaday({ field: element });
  });

  setInterval(function() {
    if ($("form input").length > formLength) {
      console.log("the updated formLength is : " + formLength);
      formLength = $("form input").length;

      var uuid = $("#uuid").html();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "trailers/" + uuid + "/save-draft",
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        success: function() {
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Nop. (" + $("form input").length + ")");
    }
  }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: You are missing trigger for your autosave logic. Wrap logic to autosave form on length change in function and call it when you make changes to the form.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my problem statement. Can you take a look again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you're drying to achieve but here is a working example :

```
var formLength = $("form input").val().length;
console.log("the current formLength is : " + formLength);

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
      if ($("form input").val().length > formLength) {
        formLength = $("form input").length;
        console.log("the updated formLength is" + formLength);
        //setTimeout(autoSaveForm, 10000); //auto save!
      } else {
        console.log("Nop. (" + $("form input").val().length + ")");   
      }    
    }, 3000);
});
```

Everything inside the document.ready fonction will only be executed once the page is loaded, so if you want to have a reccurent check you need a setInterval for example (executed periodically).

You could also add an even on your text input, for example :

```
$("form input").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
   //but your code inside
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This totally works. Solved a problem that bothered me for two days.

Comment: One question: if the form is not modified and the user does not close the page, will this recurrent function hurt performance or anything and take up resources exponentially? I don't want any recurrent tasks to kill the server.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my problem statement. Can you take a look again?

Comment: SetInterval will indeed take up some resources .. the best way would be to bind events with jquery (my second example) this will be executed only when the user change/keyup/lose focus your field and is a better way to handle this than the setInterval solution. (This will also remove your issue with the setInterval so I guess there is no point trying to debug this one ^^)